# Implementation of CKeditor in Angular2

Tags: angular, ckeditor4.x

In my project I need to implement CKeditor with Angular 2. I also need to add extra plugins, link attachment, video, audio etc. Custom plugins I need to add into plugins folder of node_modules/ckeditor or bower_components/ckeditor. If I do with npm or bower, my custom settings for extra plugins will get overridden while doing npm install or bower install. So what is the best way to do this Angular 2. Please help.

Thanks,
Dipali

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor as a direct implementation of ckeditor in angular2 itself.  If you want to use any external libraries, below are the steps to follow:

- Install the library(use npm as bower will be dead soon:P)

  `npm install <modulename/libraryname>`
- Add typescript definitions for the module

  `tsd install <modulename/libraryname>`
- Include the script in your index.html or the root html file

  `<script src=”node_modules/<modulename/libraryname>/modulename.js”></script>`
- Add the path configuration in systemsjs.config.js so that the
  SystemJs will pick the js source from this path
  `System.config({
  [...]
  paths: {
  module_var: ‘./node_modules/<modulename>/module.js’
  }
  });`
- Import the module in the component you want
  `import * as var_name from ‘module_var’;`

Now you can use the library inside this component.
Hope it works out:)